# DragDrop event not firing on object inside usercontrol (but DragEnter does)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, user-controls, drag-and-drop

Well the title pretty well describes my problem. Here is a little bit more detailed description of my problem:

I am building an application with a TabControl, which I populate at execution time with TabPages. In my first version of the code, these TabPages were filled with a children ListView. The ListView was also created in code, using AddHandlers to link it to the DragEnter and DragDrop routines. Everything worked very well...

Now as I need some other controls on every TabPage, instead of creating every single control in code, I have created a UserControl containing a ListView and a few Buttons, which I instantiate for every new TabPage.

The problem now is that the DragDrop event is not raised anymore

- `DragEnter` event --> raised OK
- `DragOver` event --> raised OK
- `DragLeave` event --> raised OK
- `DragDrop` event --> **not raised !!**

This problem is driving me crazy: any thoughts on what I could be missing?

I don't think the code will be of any help, but to answer the first comment:
**First Version: controls created in code (works):**

```
    Dim NewTab As New TabPage(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim NewListView As New ListView()
    Dim NewImageList As New ImageList()

    'Organise les nouveaux contrôles
    NewListView.Parent = NewTab
    NewListView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    NewListView.View = View.LargeIcon
    NewListView.LargeImageList = NewImageList
    NewListView.AllowDrop = True
    AddHandler NewListView.DoubleClick, AddressOf ListViewItem_DblClick
    AddHandler NewListView.DragEnter, AddressOf ListViewItem_DragEnter
    AddHandler NewListView.DragDrop, AddressOf ListViewItem_DragDrop
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
    TabControl1.SelectTab(NewTab)
    NewImageList.ImageSize = New Size(100, 100)
    NewImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth24Bit

    TabControl1.Refresh()
```

**Second version: Usercontrol (does not work):**
First, imagine a user control `TabAnnoncesContent`, which contains a `AnnoncesListView`, and an `AnnoncesImageList`

```
    Dim NewTab As New TabPage(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim NewTabContent As New TabAnnoncesContent()

    NewTabContent.Parent = NewTab
    NewTabContent.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
    TabControl1.SelectTab(NewTab)

    TabControl1.Refresh()
```

Then inside my `TabAnnoncesContent` class code I have:

```
Private Sub AnnoncesListView_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles AnnoncesListView.DragDrop
    Dim selection As ListViewItem = sender.HitTest(sender.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))).Item

    If (selection IsNot Nothing) Then
        MsgBox("D&D received -> " & e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AnnoncesListView_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles AnnoncesListView.DragEnter
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
        ' Display the copy cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link
    Else
        ' Display the no-drop cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub
```

The `AnnonceListView_DragEnter` routines is executed when I enter the ListView with text, but then when I release the mouse, the `AnnonceListView_DragDrop` event is never raised.

Comment: It is impossible to diagnose "it doesn't work!" questions like this. Post a code snippet.

Comment: I've added the code, as requested, but I highly doubt that it will be any help (standard Drag and Drop code). I was expecting something more like AllowDrop property needs to be set True here and False there or something along that ...

Comment: Look in the Output window for "First chance exception" notifications.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions to make the debugger stop on them.  The HitTest code is going to throw them.

Comment: Only one word: GENIUS !!!
How can I accept your answer since that was it: in the main form I had indeed modified the arguments of the sub handler with the first parameter sender being a ListView instead of a generic Object !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using Option Strict On in your code is a Visual Basic convenience.  You'll get runtime errors instead of compile errors when you get the code wrong.  That's doesn't work out well in drag+drop code though, the events are called with a back-stop that swallows all exceptions.  The only diagnostic you'll get is a first chance exception notification in the Output window.  Very easy to miss of course.

Anyhoo, Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox to get the debugger to stop on the exception.  And Option Strict On at the top of your source code file to catch these kind of mistakes early.  That does however require a different code writing style, more akin to C#.

Btw, you should also implement the DragOver event.  So you can call the ListView's HitTest() method and check that the user is actually hovering over a ListViewItem.